# Edmonds-Karp Algorithm with both directed and undirected edges?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, network-flow, minimum-cuts

How would this work and be implemented?

If you have directed edges pointing away from the source to a bunch of other verticies, and directed edges pointing from those vertices to a sink, but have those vertices in the middle linked by undirected edges, how would flow work and be maximized?

Answer (score 2):

Replace each undirected edge $(u,v)$ by two directed edges, one in each direction: $u\to v$ and $v\to u$.  That gives you a graph with only directed edges.  Then the max-flow on that graph is the same as the max-flow on your original graph.

Comment: That would still work? Because in Edmonds-Karp there's like a graph that represents the opposite flow of the current graph which I don't think would make sense if you have a set of edges (u,v) and (v,u).

Comment: @idontevenknow, yes, it makes sense.  You can still create the residual graph and implement Ford-Fulkerson.